# Mac | running a Python script with crontab does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, cron

I am trying to run a python script with crontab. When I run that command in the terminal it is working without any problem.

```
/usr/bin/python3 /Users/myusername/Desktop/test.py >> /Users/myusername/Desktop/cron.txt
```

But I am adding the same command to crontab like:

First:

```
crontab -e
```

Then adding that line to crontab file.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /Users/myusername/Desktop/test.py >> /Users/myusername/Desktop/cron.txt
```

It just creates the cron.txt but nothing inside it. I read a lot of problems about it and tried different ways like:

```
chmod +x test.py

* * * * * /Users/myusername/Desktop/test.py >> /Users/myusername/Desktop/cron.txt
```

Test.py file:

```
print("hello")
```

But none of them didn't t work for me. I need some help thanks.

Comment: What does ``test.py`` do? Does it use environment variables?

Comment: I edited it now. test.py is very simple just print("hello")